# C# Null Rereference Error[HELP]

Tags: c#, mysql, nullreferenceexception

I get a `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of a object error`
while running the current function. The Database jobs table,

```
 public Dictionary<uint ,JobsFacotry> Jobs = new Dictionary<uint,JobsFacotry>();

 internal void LoadJobs(IQueryAdapter dbclient)
 {      
    dbclient.setQuery("SELECT * FROM jobs");
    DataTable jobs = dbclient.getTable();
    if (jobs != null)
    {
      Jobs.Clear();
      foreach (DataRow rows in jobs.Rows)
      {
        Jobs.Add((uint)rows["job_id"], new JobsFacotry((uint)rows["job_id"],
                 (uint)rows["room_id"], (string)rows["job_name"],
                 (string)rows["jobbadge"]));

      }

     }
  }
```

the error is at the Rows when i add the field to the db but they are correct http://prntscr.com/3jd7ud

Comment: which exact line does is produce the null exception on?

Comment: I guess your are trying to parse a value that does not exist.
1 of the values in 1 row is NULL

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It is really unnerving to see two variables differ just for casing.

Comment: Put a breakpoint so you can at least identify which is the line who mess. And are you sure with the name of the column? Could you check it?

Comment: the error is on the line where the rows are entered but they do exist http://prntscr.com/3jd7ud

Comment: use debugger watch window for each of the elements in the row. this way you will be able to find the null element.

Comment: I can not debug i can build the solution and run it but debug wont work the button is just greyed out in the menu nor  does f5 work

Comment: edit- Debuger watch windows gives me nothing its blank

Comment: you need to right click the rows element and select watch in the context menu that opens.